# Sub-setting by group closest to defined value

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a dataframe where I would like to select within each group the lines where `y` is the closest to a specific value (ex.: 5).

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep("A", 4),
                       rep("B", 4)),
                 y = c(rep(4, 2), rep(1, 2), rep(6, 2), rep(3, 2)),
                 z = rnorm(8))

df

##   x y          z
## 1 A 4 -1.2070657
## 2 A 4  0.2774292
## 3 A 1  1.0844412
## 4 A 1 -2.3456977
## 5 B 6  0.4291247
## 6 B 6  0.5060559
## 7 B 3 -0.5747400
## 8 B 3 -0.5466319
```

The result would be:

```
##   x y          z
## 1 A 4 -1.2070657
## 2 A 4  0.2774292
## 3 B 6  0.4291247
## 4 B 6  0.5060559
```

Thank you, Philippe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(
    delta = abs(y - 5)
  ) %>%
  filter(delta == min(delta)) %>%
  select(-delta)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively using base R:

```
 df[do.call(c, tapply(df$y, df$x, function(x) x-5 == max(x - 5))),]
  x y          z
1 A 4 -1.2070657
2 A 4  0.2774292
5 B 6  0.4291247
6 B 6  0.5060559
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'x', we create get the absolute difference of 'y' with 5, check for elements that are `min` from the difference, get the row index (`.I`), extract the column that is row index ("V1") and subset the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, {v1 <- abs(y-5)
               .I[v1==min(v1)]}, x]$V1]
#   x y          z
#1: A 4 -1.2070657
#2: A 4  0.2774292
#3: B 6  0.4291247
#4: B 6  0.5060559
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val <- 5
delta <- abs(val - df$y)
df <- df[delta == min(delta), ]
```

Comment: you don's need to specify the cols

Comment: add this won't use the grouping on `x`

Comment: I was specifying the cols because I didn't want the diff column to be included with the output data frame, as it isn't really supposed to be part of it.

Comment: you can keep the diff as a vector output of the dataframe